# Angular Library - Service and Object Model

Tags: angular, typescript

Im following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@tomsu/how-to-build-a-library-for-angular-apps-4f9b38b0ed11

to create an Angular Library of Components, Models and Services.

Components parts works well and I can import them into my destination project.

I have problems with models and services.

**MODELS**

I usually create a TS class to manage data I get from REST API.

For example I create a D3Dashboard.ts class:

```
    //d3dashboard.ts

export default class D3Dashboard 
    {
        id                      : Number;
        name                    : String;
        reference_name          : String;

        constructor(dict = null)
        {
          if (dict !== null)
          {
            this.id                     = dict["id"];
            this.name                   = dict["name"];
            this.reference_name         = dict["reference_name"];
          }
        }
    }
```

Then I import it in public-api.ts

```
export * from './lib/models/D3Dashboard';
```

In my app I tried to use D3Dashboard:

```
import { D3Dashboard }                        from 'dashboard3';
```

where dashboard3 is the name of the library (like when I import components).
Compiler fails with this error:

```
"export 'D3Dashboard' was not found in 'dashboard3'
```

I think this is a consequence of a problem I already have with other models.
In my main-app I always import them like:

```
import MyTsClass from './models/MyTsClass.ts';
```

When I tried with this syntax:

```
import { MyTsClass } from './models/MyTsClass.ts';
```

I get:

```
"export 'MyTsClass ' was not found in '../../models/MyTsClass'
```

**SERVICES**

I create a test service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DashboardService {

  constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient) { }

  getFoo():Observable<any>
  {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>("http://www.google.it",{ }).pipe(map((response: any) => response));
  }
}
```

I have included it in public-api.ts:

```
export * from './lib/service/dashboard.service';
```

In my app:

```
import { DashboardService }                   from 'dashboard3';
[...]
   constructor(injector: Injector,
               private dashboard_service: DashboardService ) 
   {
       super(injector);
   }
[...]

 ngOnInit() 
  {
     this.dashboard_service.getFoo().subscribe(
       data => {
           console.log(data);
       },
       err => {
           console.log("we gonna die");
       });
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePageComponent -> DashboardService]:
```

**--------------------------------**
**UPDATE:**
**--------------------------------**

While waiting the final answer, I find out the solution of Models Problem and get a new error for service:

About Models, I've removed "default" from export class as suggested and then changed this row in public.api.ts:

```
// models
export { D3Dashboard } from './lib/models/D3Dashboard';
```

Now D3Dashboard is accessible in main-app with:

```
import { D3Dashboard }                           from '@d3/common';
```

Regarding the service, I have import HttpClientModule in library app.module and added service in provider array:

```
import { HttpClientModule }       from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DashSettingsComponent],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  exports: [ DashSettingsComponent ],
  providers: [ DashboardService ],
})
export class D3CommonModule { }
```

In my app I get this error now:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpHandler -> Injector]:
```

Comment: Please ask about one thing at a time. If you `export default class D3Dashboard { ... }`, then the correct import is `import D3Dashboard from "path/to/file";`

Comment: Don't use `export default`, just use `export` and you are good to go